# Create tree using html and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tree

I have Christmas Tree image background like attached, but without fruits. I want create the fruits (maybe a icon image) by random quantity and position, but the position must be within the range of the foliage (red mark).
Any css or js can do this?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: what about to use CANVAS ?

Comment: @genadimumladze I do not know, can you please guide more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to created an array included coordinates of the fruits (it's very very much), then get random from that array.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me - given this picture - I would probably pick a random location in a rectangle containing the tree and test for the pixel there having substantially more green than other components - if not found, try again (probably put a limit of 100 tries or so, in case the tree gets filled up).  That would also keep you from placing a new one directly on another ornament (though not prevent overlap, of course).  This seems a lot simpler than trying to define the outline of the tree.  This also lets you change the background picture to a different tree or even a forest of trees.

Comment: I don't do stackoverflow for cash, but if I have some extra time this weekend, I'll throw something together and edit my answer.  No commitment, no charge!